# validation errors in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have some problems while working with rails any help would be appreciated. i have an action

```
def submit_solution
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    @gallary = @event.gallaries.new
end
```

and from this it goes to the view

```
<%= form_for @gallary do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @gallary %>

    <div class="field">
       <%= f.label :image %><br>
       <%= f.file_field :image %>
    </div>
    <div> 
       <%= hidden_field_tag(:event_id, @event.id) %>
       <%= f.submit 'Upload', class: "btn btn-primary", controller: 'events', action: 'image_upload'%>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

now if i upload the file then it's running smoothly but when i submit it without uploading the file. its not showing the validation errors. it's giving the error

```
param is missing or the value is empty: gallary
```

my gallary params

```
def gallary_params
    params.require(:gallary).permit(:image, :event_id)
end
```

my image_upload action is

```
def image_upload
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @gallary = @event.gallaries.build(gallary_params)
    if @gallary.save
        flash[:success] = "Image uploaded"
        redirect_to controller: 'events', action: 'event_info', id: @event.id
    else
        flash[:danger] = "error while uploading image"
        redirect_to controller: 'events', action: 'submit_solution', id: @event.id
    end
end
```

anyone can tell me why this is happening ??

Comment: Post your image_upload action

Comment: Inspect your params that are being submitted. `:gallary` is not being submitted.

Comment: @jdgray yeah they are not, but in the case i upload the file then its being submitted. i just want to know why this behavior. it should atleast submit the :gallary be it nil

Comment: Because your `gallary_params` require `:image`. So thats why it works upon submission. What do your params look like when submitted without `:image`?

Comment: @jdgray yeah i know it requires :image, but if i am not submitting it, then i just want to show the error message to my user, like file not uploaded so that they can upload it again .

Comment: "<%= hidden_field_tag(:event_id, @event.id) %>" -- This indicates a serious problem with your code structure. You're not using the Rails-way of implementing a form with submit action.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%= form_for @gallary do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: @gallary %>

  <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :image %><br>
   <%= f.file_field :image %>
  </div>
 <div> 
   <%= f.hidden_field :event_id, :value => @event.id %>
   <%= f.submit 'Upload', class: "btn btn-primary", controller: 'events', action: 'image_upload'%>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

then:

```
def image_upload
  @event = Event.find(params[:gallary][:event_id])
  @gallary = @event.gallaries.build(gallary_params)
  if @gallary.save
    flash[:success] = "Image uploaded"
    redirect_to controller: 'events', action: 'event_info', id: @event.id
  else
    flash[:danger] = "error while uploading image"
    redirect_to controller: 'events', action: 'submit_solution', id: @event.id
  end
end
```